# how to remove prompt character from kendo maskedtextbox mvvm value binding

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-mobile, kendo-mvvm

I am using Kendo UI Masked Textbox and MVVM value binding.

The viewmodel phonenumber does not contain any prompt characters like "()-" it contains simply the numbers.

`var viewModel = kendo.observable({
     phoneNumber: "1234567890",
     onChange: function () {
         alert("event :: change " + this.get("phoneNumber"));
     }
 });
 kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);`

When you change the value in the form and inspect the viewModel phoneNumber (see onchange function). The phoneNumber now contains special/prompt characters e.g. `phoneNumber: "(444) 555-5555"`

This is my problem, i expect the value of the MaskedTextbox to return only numbers `phoneNumber: "4445555555"` not with the special characters.

[Full Code Snippet @JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jLu3j7us/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more research and found the [answer](http://www.telerik.com/forums/looking-for-a-way-to-strip-the-mask-before-posting)

Workaround for unmasking values that are databound to an observable when using MVVM. A single maskedtextbox change event handler can strip the formatting for any value binding:

`<ul data-role="listview">
   <li>
       <label>
           Home Phone:
           <input type="text" data-role="maskedtextbox" data-bind="value: homePhone, events: { change: maskStrip }" data-mask="(000) 000-0000" />
       </label>
   </li>
   <li>
       <label>
           Cell Phone:
           <input type="text" data-role="maskedtextbox" data-bind="value: cellPhone, events: { change: maskStrip }" data-mask="(000) 000-0000"/>
       </label>
   </li>
</ul>`

`var vm = kendo.observable({
    homePhone: null,
    cellPhone: null,
    maskStrip: function (e) {
        var that = e.sender,
            stripped = that._unmask(that.value()), 
            obs = e.data,
            val = that.element.data("bind");
        if (val) {
            val = val.substring(val.indexOf('value: ') + 7); //remove properties before
            if (val.indexOf(',') > -1) val = val.substring(0, val.indexOf(',')); //remove properties after
            obs.set(val, stripped);
        }
    }
});`

Comment: Please add the answer to your post, in case the URL dies. Also, accept your own answer. :)